# List Multiple Global Variables Into One Cell That Change In For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have two global variables `ErrorMsg` and `SectionName`. What I want my macro to do is run through the code and if `ErrorMsg` is assigned a value, I want it to list the `SectionName` and then the `ErrorMsg` that was generated within that section. There are cases where `ErrorMsg` could appear in multiple different `SectionNames` thats why I want it to be labeled which Section generated the `ErrorMsg`.

There will be cases where there are more than two values for `ErrorMsg` so I need the macro to recognize all the values of `ErrorMsg` and `SectionName` list them.

So if errors are generated in lines `wavelength_col = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Wavelength (nm)")` and `power_value = Getdata(ws, sysrow, power_col)`

Then the output in `With logsht` should look like this with each new Section font bolded.

`Complete with Error - Section: Wavelength - Wavelength column index could not be found, Section: Power - data could not be found`

Here are the functions I mentioned above.

```
Global ErrorMsg As String, SectionName As String 

Sub Main 
Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, sysnum As String, sysrow As Integer, wb As Workbook, logsht As Worksheet 

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 
Set ws = ActiveWorksheet 
Set logsht = wb.Worksheets("Log Sheet") 

For Each cell In ws.Range("E2", ws.cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).cells 
sysnum = cell.Value
sysrow = cell.row

power_col = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Power (mW)")
power_value = GetJiraData(ws, sysrow, power_col)

Dim begincell As Long
With logsht 
    begincell = .cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    .cells(begincell + 1, 2).Value = sysnum
    .cells(begincell + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
If Not ErrorMsg = "" Then
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Value = "Complete with Erorr - " & ErrorMsg
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
Else
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Value = "Completed without Errors"
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
    .cells(begincell + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
End If
End With

Next cell 

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Wavelength()
Dim wavelength_col As Long, wavelength_value As Double
SectionName = "Wavelength"
On Error GoTo errormessage
wavelength_col = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Wavelength (nm)")
wavelength_value = Getdata(ws, sysrow, wavelength_col) 
Exit Sub
errormessage:
ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Power()
Dim power_col As Long, power_value As Double
SectionName = "Power"
On Error GoTo errormessage
power_col = GetColumnIndex(ws, "Average Power (mW)")
power_value = Getdata(ws, sysrow, power_col)
Exit Sub
errormessage:
ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg
End Sub
```

---

```
Function GetColumnIndex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Double 
Dim paramname As Range
Set paramname = sht.Range("A1", sht.cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).cells.Find(What:=colname, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True) 
    If Not paramname Is Nothing Then 
        GetColumnIndex = paramname.column
    ElseIf paramname Is Nothing Then '
            ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", ", ") & colname & " column index could not be found" 
    End If
End Function
```

---

```
Function Getdata(sht As Worksheet, WDrow As Long, parametercol As Long) As Variant 
Getdata = sht.cells(WDrow, parametercol)
If Getdata = -999 Then 
ElseIf Getdata = Empty Then
        ErrorMsg = ErrorMsg & IIf(ErrorMsg = "", "", ", ") & "data could not be found" 
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, there are several things wrong in your code.

Just to name a few;

your `Power()` sub uses `ws` as a WorkSheet object yet they are not declared as `Global` under the `Main` method nor are they used as parameters for the sub and hence will not be available? Same applies for `Wavelength`.

`Power()` and `Wavelenght()` both produce a variable yet you do not seem to do anything with those values?

But alas, for the solution;

What you can do is add a `ClassModule` to your project and give it below fields and name it 'ErrorState'

```
Option Explicit
Public ErrMsg As String
Public ErrNumber As Long
Public SectionName As String 'suggest to use 'MethodName' but your pick
```

Then in your `CodeModule` declare a `new Collection` as a a `Global` collection

```
Global Errors As New Collection
```

Then add a Method (a Sub if you wish) that adds the error to the collection.

```
Private Sub AddError(message As String, number As Long, method As String)
    Dim error As New ErrorState
    error.ErrMsg = message
    error.SectionName = method
    error.ErrNumber = number
    Errors.Add error
End Sub
```

Add the above correctly to your ErrorHandling as per below example

```
Sub Power(sht As Worksheet, sysrow As Long)
    On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Err.Raise (13) 'you can remove this, this is just to trigger an Error
    Dim power_col As Long, power_value As Double
    power_col = GetColumnIndex(sht, "Average Power (mW)")
    power_value = Getdata(sht, sysrow, power_col)
    Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
    AddError Err.Description, Err.number, "Power"
End Sub
```

So your complete code would look like the below (I have simplified the `Main` method, but I'm sure you get the picture)

```
Global Errors As New Collection

Private Sub AddError(message As String, number As Long, method As String)
    Dim error As New ErrorState
    error.ErrMsg = message
    error.SectionName = method
    error.ErrNumber = number
    Errors.Add error
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Set Errors = New Collection
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Wavelength ws, 1
    Power ws, 1
    Index = GetColumnIndex(ws, "SomeColum")
    Data = Getdata(ws, 1, 1)
    
    For Each e In Errors
        Debug.Print e.SectionName, e.ErrMsg, e.ErrNumber
    Next
End Sub

Sub Wavelength(sht As Worksheet, sysrow As Long)
    On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Dim wavelength_col As Long, wavelength_value As Double
    wavelength_col = GetColumnIndex(sht, "Wavelength (nm)")
    wavelength_value = Getdata(sht, sysrow, wavelength_col) 'do you need to do anything with this value?
    Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
    AddError Err.Description, Err.number, "Wavelength"
End Sub

Sub Power(sht As Worksheet, sysrow As Long)
    On Error GoTo ErrorExit
    Dim power_col As Long, power_value As Double
    power_col = GetColumnIndex(sht, "Average Power (mW)")
    power_value = Getdata(sht, sysrow, power_col) 'do you need to do anything with this value?
    Exit Sub
ErrorExit:
    AddError Err.Description, Err.number, "Power"
End Sub

Function GetColumnIndex(sht As Worksheet, colname As String) As Double
    Dim paramname As Range
    Set paramname = sht.Range("A1", sht.Cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells.Find(What:=colname, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True)        
    
    If Not paramname Is Nothing Then
        GetColumnIndex = paramname.Column
    Else
        AddError Trim(colname & " column index could not be found"), 0, "GetColumnIndex"
    End If
End Function

Function Getdata(sht As Worksheet, WDrow As Long, parametercol As Long) As Variant
    Getdata = sht.Cells(WDrow, parametercol)
        
    If Getdata = -999 Then
        'do something
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Getdata) Then
         AddError "data could not be found", 0, "Getdata"
    End If
End Function
```